# Vagrant - Port forwarding behavior with private networks

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualbox

I am testing nginx setup with vagrant but I seem to be missing some minute detail because of which when I try to reach nginx from host on a static ip, the connection times out. My Vagrant file:

```
   # -*- mode: ruby -*-
   # vi: set ft=ruby :
   $script = <<-SCRIPT
     sudo apt-get -y update
     sudo apt-get install -y nginx
   SCRIPT

   ###################################
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   # webserver server
   config.vm.define "webserver" do |webserver|
      webserver.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
      webserver.ssh.insert_key = false
      webserver.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.101"
      webserver.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80 , host: 4000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
      webserver.vm.hostname = "webserver"
      webserver.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sed 's/127\.0\.0\.1.*webserver.*/192\.168\.10\.101 webserver/' -i /etc/hosts"
      webserver.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      # Customize VM
       vb.name = "webserver"
       vb.memory = "1024"
       vb.cpus = "2"
      end
   end
 end
```

I am able to reach nginx vi localhost:4000 but if I do http://192.168.10.101:4000, the connection times out. I have also tried to stop firewall as below:

```
 vagrant@webserver:~$ sudo ufw disable
 Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

Does not help. Any guidance on this please?

EDIT - 1

I removed the virtualbox private network after reading documentation at https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html. However, the issue is bit confusing because now I can access nginx test page at :
http://192.168.10.101 but not at http://192.168.10.101:4000. Although I can access http://localhost:4000. May be I am missing something.

EDIT - 2

Ran a python simplehttpserver in the vm and forwarded port:

```
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Vagrantfile

```
   dbserver.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000 , host: 5000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

But I can access my test page :

http://192.168.10.102:8000/

but not as

http://192.168.10.102:5000/

So this makes me think that there is some rule that allows me to access my virtualbox ports without actual port forwarding on private networks.

```
  $> netstat -nr
  Routing tables

  Internet:
  Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
  default            192.168.0.1        UGSc           40        0     en0
  127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
  127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              4    57934     lo0
  169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
  192.168.0          link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
  192.168.0.1/32     link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
  192.168.0.1        c0:a0:bb:c6:f5:58  UHLWIir        48     6051     en0   1188
  192.168.0.101/32   link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
  192.168.10         link#17            UC              2        0 vboxnet
  192.168.10.102     8:0:27:1b:d5:98    UHLWI           0       73 vboxnet    586
  224.0.0/4          link#4             UmCS            2        0     en0
  224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
  239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0     1067     en0
  255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
```

Comment: try commenting `forwarded_port` line and do `vagrant up`. and verify whether you are able to access?

Comment: I did, and it forwards port 22 only now.                                                      
        ==> webserver: Forwarding ports...
               webserver: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1).                           I can still access the nginx test page on port 80. I seem to miss some point about the forwarding mechanism

Comment: if you are able to fix, it is great. if still issue, then let me know, but i need to do that setup in my local system and try. :) I will try to do that and update you, if you still getting issue.

Comment: Thanks @Haranadh. It is not really not an issue now but rather curiosity to understand what the behavior is. It would be great if you can give it a try and see if this is what happens at your end as well

Comment: Tried the setup in my local machine, and shared my findings as answer. I am also facing same as you. `forwarded_port` is not really doing its job unlike docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to analyze and found in [vagrant site.](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html).

Even though they have given `Defining a Forwarded Port`, they mentioned disclaimer as following content.

> For most providers, forwarded ports by default bind to all interfaces. This means that other devices on your network can access the forwarded ports. If you want to restrict access, see the guest_ip and host_ip settings below.

The virtualbox provider seems doing the trick in this case. It is default fwding the guest-machine ports.
I also felt this `forwarded_port` option for network configuration did not worked well.

---

I tried the same setup with given above vagrant file in my machine.

**My observations:**

- Script part of your vagrant file did not install `nginx` in my local `vagrant`.
- I tried manually install the `nginx` in my local `vagrant`, and made it running.
- I was able to see the `nginx` homepage of guest-machine from host-machine's browser.
- In guest-machine `nginx` running on default 80 port. and in host-machine could access from port `80` itself.

---

**Conclusion from the link is :**

> For most providers, forwarded ports by default bind to all interfaces.

---

**Edit:**
Even tried with sample python server running in the `guest-machine`, and tested, could access the python-webserver without any fwding port in vagrant setup.

*Following is output from python server in vagrant:*

```
(envflask) vagrant@webserver:~/test$ ls
flasktest.py
(envflask) vagrant@webserver:~/test$ python flasktest.py 
Starting RestServer at port 9595
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:9595/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2017 13:35:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2017 13:35:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: @f-z-n: if my answer clarifies your question and if you likes my answer, please accept.